# How to extend a parent babel config?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, monorepo

With eslint, I can do this:

```
.eslintrc.js
packages/
  foo/
    .eslintrc.js
  bar/
    .eslintrc.js
```

Where the child `.eslintrc.js` looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": ["react-app", "../../.eslintrc.js"]
}
```

Can I do this with babel configuration files? I know about `--root-mode=upward`, but I don't think that helps here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to this article: [So What's New in Babel 7](https://blog.bitsrc.io/so-whats-new-in-babel-7-ea97cb984ef0).

Since v7, you can add [overrides](https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/08/27/7.0.0#selective-configuration-with-overrides) to your configuration file:

```js
//babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [ ... ],
    overrides: [
    {
      test: ["./packages/bar"],
      presets: ["@babel/preset-react"],
    },
  ],
}
```

Where:

- test = the glob pattern to match a certain path in your repository
- presets = the presets you want to add to your selective configuration (note that the default presets are preserved)